# Highcharts export with custom HTML graph

Tags: highcharts

I am generating a custom legend as an HTML table.  I would like to be able to include it when using the export function.  Is this possible, or will I have to use the useHTML function?

Any thoughts?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brookssh/hQqVU/1/)

var chart;

```
chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'chartContainer',
        height: 500, // 600,
        width: 1150,
        type: 'column',
        defaultSeriesType: 'spline',
        backgroundColor: null,
        reflow: false,
        shadow: false,
        //marginLeft: 60,
        //spacingTop: 10,
        spacingBottom: 100,
        width: 1150,
        events: {
            load: function () {

            }
        }
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: true,
        useHTML: true,
        layout: 'vertical',
        formatter: function () {
            return '<td>' + this.name + '</td>';
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: "Power",
        style: {
            color: '#484a4a',
            fontSize: '22px',
            fontFamily: 'Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif',
            fontWeight: 'bold'
        }
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: "Wednesday, January 01 2014 through Saturday, January 18 2014",
        y: 36,
        style: {
            color: '#7e8081'
        }
    },
    xAxis: [{
        title: {
            text: 'Time',
            style: {
                color: '#0063A2',
                fontFamily: 'Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif',
                fontWeight: 'bold'
            }
        },
        type: 'datetime',
        dateTimeLabelFormats: {
            second: '%H:%M:%S',
            minute: '%H:%M',
            hour: '%I:%M %p',
            day: '%b %d',
            month: '%B',
            year: '%Y'
        },
        plotBands: [{
            color: '#DDECFF',
            from: 1388768400000,
            to: 1388941200000
        }, {
            color: '#DDECFF',
            from: 1389373200000,
            to: 1389546000000
        }, {
            color: '#DDECFF',
            from: 1389978000000,
            to: 1390150800000
        }, {
            color: '#DDECFF',
            from: 1390582800000,
            to: 1390755600000
        }]

    }, {
        labels: {
            enabled: false
        },
        lineWidth: 0,
        tickWidth: 0
    }],
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Consumption (kWh)',
            style: {
                color: '#0063A2',
                fontFamily: 'Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif',
                fontWeight: 'bold'
            }
        },
        min: 0,
        plotLines: [{
            value: 0,
            width: 2,
            color: '#000000'
        }]
    },
    tooltip: {

        enable: true,
        formatter: function () {
            return Highcharts.dateFormat('%A, %b %e, %Y - %I:%M %P', this.x) + '<br/>' + '<span style=color:#0063A2;>' + this.series.name.split('|')[1] + '</span> : ' + '<b>' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2) + ' kWh' + '</b>'
        }



    },
    plotOptions: {

        spline: {
            enableMouseTracking: true,
            animation: {
                duration: 1500
            },
            marker: {
                enabled: false,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        enabled: true,
                        symbol: 'circle',
                        radius: 5,
                        lineWidth: 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: "Building 1|Meter 1|870.68 kWh",
        visible: true,
        showInLegend: true,
        xAxis: 0,

        data: [
            [1388534400000, 65.598914000000000000],
            [1388620800000, 68.851831000000000000],
            [1388707200000, 60.547108000000000000],
            [1388793600000, 51.878880000000000000],
            [1388880000000, 46.766490000000000000],
            [1388966400000, 47.069411000000000000],
            [1389052800000, 54.288275000000000000],
            [1389139200000, 59.740870000000000000],
            [1389225600000, 49.483467000000000000],
            [1389312000000, 47.307088000000000000],
            [1389398400000, 39.515004000000000000],
            [1389484800000, 46.416965000000000000],
            [1389571200000, 46.892318000000000000],
            [1389657600000, 39.748021000000000000],
            [1389744000000, 47.707878000000000000],
            [1389830400000, 52.755024000000000000],
            [1389916800000, 46.109382000000000000]
        ]

    }, {
        name: "Building 1|Meter 2|1551.64 kWh",
        visible: true,
        showInLegend: true,
        xAxis: 0,

        data: [
            [1388534400000, 44.189323000000000000],
            [1388620800000, 109.177733000000000000],
            [1388707200000, 108.329552000000000000],
            [1388793600000, 50.555344000000000000],
            [1388880000000, 54.558574000000000000],
            [1388966400000, 111.037208000000000000],
            [1389052800000, 106.283663000000000000],
            [1389139200000, 91.240093000000000000],
            [1389225600000, 110.277573000000000000],
            [1389312000000, 115.203550000000000000],
            [1389398400000, 51.361583000000000000],
            [1389484800000, 50.476118000000000000],
            [1389571200000, 109.615805000000000000],
            [1389657600000, 108.753643000000000000],
            [1389744000000, 113.507186000000000000],
            [1389830400000, 112.714930000000000000],
            [1389916800000, 104.354283000000000000]
        ]

    }, {
        name: "Building 1|Meter 3|1400.82 kWh",
        visible: true,
        showInLegend: true,
        xAxis: 0,

        data: [
            [1388534400000, 37.352607000000000000],
            [1388620800000, 94.506990000000000000],
            [1388707200000, 90.280063000000000000],
            [1388793600000, 36.979780000000000000],
            [1388880000000, 40.526298000000000000],
            [1388966400000, 99.731228000000000000],
            [1389052800000, 108.977339000000000000],
            [1389139200000, 113.311452000000000000],
            [1389225600000, 100.197263000000000000],
            [1389312000000, 103.398914000000000000],
            [1389398400000, 37.813981000000000000],
            [1389484800000, 44.259228000000000000],
            [1389571200000, 98.668671000000000000],
            [1389657600000, 92.367895000000000000],
            [1389744000000, 107.649142000000000000],
            [1389830400000, 102.261792000000000000],
            [1389916800000, 92.540327000000000000]
        ]

    }]
}, function (chart) {
    var options = chart.options.legend;

    /**
     * What happens when the user clicks the legend item
     */
    function clickItem(series, $legendItem, $line) {
        series.setVisible();
        $legendItem.css(
        options[series.visible ? 'itemStyle' : 'itemHiddenStyle']);
        if (series.visible) $legendItem.css({
            color: series.color
        });
        $line.css({
            borderTop: '2px solid ' + (series.visible ? series.color : options.itemHiddenStyle.color)
        });
    }

    var $legendcontainer = $("<div id='centerdiv' class='highcharts-legend'>").appendTo($(".createGraph"));
    // Create the legend box
    var $legend = $('<table>')
        .css({
        width: 800,
        //maxHeight: 210,
        //left:175,
        padding: 10,
        //position: 'absolute',
        overflow: 'auto',

        //top: 510,
        borderColor: options.borderColor,
        borderWidth: options.borderWidth,
        borderStyle: 'solid',
        borderRadius: options.borderRadius
    })
        .appendTo($legendcontainer);

    var $headerrow = $("<tr>").appendTo($legend);
    $("<th>").appendTo($headerrow);
    $("<th>").html("Building Name").appendTo($headerrow);
    $("<th>").html("Meter Name").appendTo($headerrow);

    $("<th>").html("Total Consumption").appendTo($headerrow);

    $.each(chart.series, function (i, series) {
        var data = series.name.split('|');

        //shift columns to the right for formatting
        if (data[0] == "Aggregate") {
            data[2] = data[1];
            data[1] = data[0];
            data[0] = "";
        }
        // create the legend item            
        var $legendItem = $('<tr>')
            .css({
            position: 'relative',
            marginLeft: 20
        })
            .css(options[series.visible ? 'itemStyle' : 'itemHiddenStyle'])
            .css({
            color: series.color
        })
            .html("<td></td><td>" + data[0] + "</td><td>" + data[1] + "</td><td>" + data[2] + "</td>")
            .appendTo($legend);

        // create the line with each series color
        var $line = $('<div>')
            .css({
            width: 16,
            float: 'left',
            borderTop: '2px solid ' + (series.visible ? series.color : options.itemHiddenStyle.color)
        })
            .prependTo($($legendItem).find("td").first());

        // click handler 
        $legendItem.click(function () {
            clickItem(series, $legendItem, $line);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: The problem is that you are using callback, but should be `chart.events.load`. Only things in load are used for exporting.

Answer (score 2):

Try checking the code out [here](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/frequently-asked-questions#add-data-table).

Comment: So far, that's doing what I need to do.  The only thing that is now missing, is the ability to add an event handler to provide the same functionality of the generated legend (clicking on legend items to make bars/lines hide and show.  Any thoughts?

Comment: You can do that by wrapping in a series object function. Something like: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/series-hide/

Comment: Can this be done, even though the table I am generating is SVG, and not HTML?

Answer (score 1):

As of version 4.1.8, Highcharts has a new attribute called `allowHTML` that will permit HTML elements rendered within a chart (using `renderer.html`, for example) to show up in exported versions (PDF, PNG, etc.).

Here are the details on `allowHTML` in the API documentation:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#exporting.allowHTML

> **allowHTML: Boolean**
>
> Experimental setting to allow HTML
>   inside the chart (added through the `useHTML` options), directly in the
>   exported image. This allows you to preserve complicated HTML
>   structures like tables or bi-directional text in exported charts.
>
> Disclaimer: The HTML is rendered in a `foreignObject` tag in the
>   generated SVG. The official export server is based on PhantomJS, which
>   supports this, but other SVG clients, like Batik, does not support it.
>   This also applies to downloaded SVG that you want to open in a desktop
>   client.
>
> *Defaults to `false`.*

One thing to keep in mind: if you style any of the HTML you're using in your charts, you need to use inline styles (vs. classes) in order for that formatting to show up on the exported versions.